# Imprimary Intergration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have an exercise that requires us to compute this double integration:
$\int\int e^{-y^2}dxdy $ on $D\equiv \bigtriangleup OAB$ here $O(0;0)$, $A(1;0)$, $B(0;1)$.
It is easy to transform the given integral into this form:
$\int_{0}^{1}e^{-y^2}(1-y)dy$. I think we can't solve this $\int_{0}^{1}dx\int_{0}^{1-x}e^{-y^2}dy$ because the second integral is not primary and the remaining task is evaluate the 1st integral.
Do you have any trick or idea that help me finish above problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} e^{-y^2} dy dx = \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} ~\text{erf}~(1-x) dx = \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} ~\text{erf}~(x)dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\left[x ~\text{erf}~(x) + \frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right]_0^1 = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}(\text{erf}(1) + \frac{1}{e \sqrt{\pi}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\text{erf}(1) + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{e} - 1\right) = 0.430764$$

Comment: Oh. Thank you. I hadn't known "erf" function until you showed up your answer. We got easy way to calculate the integral. However, how can we do it by just using basic techniques, basic functions such as logarithmic, algebraic, trigonometric, exponential?

Comment: I am afraid, we cannot!